# Using DFS to detect cycles in Tideman

Tags: c, cs50, depth-first-search

Why isn't that algorithm working to detect cycles?

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // array[0] being true means that there is an edge or more pointing at candidate number 0
    bool array[candidate_count];
    for (int l = 0; l < pair_count; l++)
    {
        // add an edge, as long as it doesn't make a cycle
        if (!will_cycle(array, pairs[l].loser))
        {
            locked[pairs[l].winner][pairs[l].loser] = true;
            array[pairs[l].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}
// index is the index of the candidate the edge will be pointing at if it's added
// the function temporarily sets array[index] as true, like there's an edge pointing at it
// the function then iterates over all the array array, if they're all true it means there'll be a cycle.
// so it's undo the array[index] to false again.
// and if there's at least one false in the array array, it means there won't be a cycle
bool will_cycle(bool array[], int index) // return true if it will make a cycle
{
    array[index] = true;
    int flag = 0; // var for number of true candidates
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (array[i])
            flag++;
    }

    if (flag == candidate_count) // they're all true
    {
        array[index] = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Although (in my understanding) a cycle in the graph means a graph with no source, and a source is a candidate with no edges pointing at them, so the "array" array being all true means all candidates are having at least one edge pointing at them, so it's a cycle.

Why can't that pass check50 test regarding lock_pair skipping pairs that will lead to a cycle, although I tested it and it worked fine?
Why do I have to use some sort of algorithm like DFS, why check50 doesn't like that?

I tried testing the example of Alice, Charlie and Bob found on background header in the pset page on cs50 website. I traced it, and I saw my algorithm just worked fine in skipping the last pair (which gave a cycle), and it even gave the correct winner's name.

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output, and integrate that example in your code making it runnable, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not needed @trincot its all on the CS50 site... if he did it would bloat the problem...  yes i realize that normally I would say exactly what you said but this is truly enough in this case to answer the problem. because all the other code wouldnt be his.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your understanding of what a cycle is in a graph is incorrect.

A graph has a cycle if there is a path that leads from a node back to itself.  So for example `A->B->C-A` has as cycle. No matter what other edges you add to it, there is an 'infinite' path that can be made from A back to A. That is what we dont not want.

As a result your code to a cycle is flat out wrong.
Consider you have 5 candidates, `a,b,c,d,e`
if you have pairs `(a,b), and (b,c)` you can't add `(c,a)` because that would produce a cycle. `a->b->c->a`

So the problem is your algorithm is wrong. Further you are not using a depth first search.  You aren't traversing the depth at all. The only thing you are doing is checking if this would make every single candidate a loser to someone. which is not the base case.  **This is however very close to what you would need to do to detect a winner in the next step.**   The winner is the node which is only a source and has no edges leading into it.

You need to ask yourself what are you looking for, what would occur if there was a cycle? and then prevent that.. There are a number of ways to do it.  You could walk from winner to loser continually until you found there either was a cycle or there wasn't.  You can see if you start from the loser and go backwards if theres locked pair where your path of losers is ever the winner over your initial winner.    In all cases you will need to pass in initially both members of the pair you are proposing to add to the graph.